# Cant Insert into SQL Table or Show all from

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant seem to access my table. Once again I'm sure its something simple I'm overlooking. I'm not getting any errors. Nothing is being added to the table and nothing shows up. I have renamed everything several times, made sure the connection is good, made sure the table exists. I cannot see anything wrong.

Add Data to Table

```
    // Valid Data
    require_once('resources/php/db.php');
    $id = uniqid();

    //die ( $id . $name . $sex. $age. $hair. $eye. $skin. $body. $pf );

    // Insert Data to the Table
    $statement1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO player VALUES(:player_id, :name, :sex, :age, :hair, :eye, :skin, :body, :pf)');
    $result1 = $statement1 -> execute(array(
        ':player_id' =>$id,
        ':name' =>$name,
        ':sex' =>$sex,
        ':age' =>$age,
        ':hair' =>$hair,
        ':eye' =>$eye,
        ':skin' =>$skin,
        ':body' =>$body,
        ':pf' =>$pf
    ));

    // Make Sure Everything Worked
    if( $result1 == false )
    {
        die('Update Failed, Please Check Your Database.');
    }

    header("Location: ../../new_success.php?id=$id;");
    exit();
```

Success Page

```
 // Start the Load
$query1 = "SELECT * 
           FROM player
           WHERE player_id = :player_id";

$statement1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$statement1 -> execute(array(
    ':player_id' =>$id
));

// Make Sure the Data Exists
if( $statement1->rowCount() == 0 )
{
    die('Please Enter a Valid ID Tag - (id)');
}
else
{
    $notEmpty = true;   
}


while($row = $statement1->fetch())
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $sex = $row['sex'];
    $age = $row['age'];
    $hair = $row['hair'];
    $eye = $row['eye'];
    $skin = $row['skin'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $pf = $row['pf'];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is a query error, ie from MySQL?

Comment: Yes im using pdo. The db file hasnt changed at all it. I use it for all the database connections. As for query error none that i have found.

Comment: You are missing `:`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo). If thats the case, you are missing `:` in `execute` method. It should be `:player_id` not `player_id`.

```
$statement1 -> execute(array(
    ':player_id' =>$id
));
```

Same way the second query is also not proper.

```
$result1 = $statement1 -> execute(array(
        ':player_id' =>$id,
        ':name' =>$name,
         ...
    ));
```

[php.net example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-990).

Comment: I removed the select query part. Ill worry about it after this part. I tried it your way still no luck. I have check the data before it goes in its all there and correct. I changed it to the way you said same problem. I dont think that : is the problem i have used it the way i showed before and it works fine. I updated my to post to show the code

Comment: Could you show the result of `var_dump($db->errorInfo())` and `var_dump($result1->errorInfo())` ?

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } 
Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in new_character.php on line 79

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "23000" [1]=> int(1048) [2]=> string(26) "Column 'pf' cannot be null" } Update Failed, Please Check Your Database. (Thanks for Helping me!)

Comment: Ok so i got it now lol. PF was stuck in loop and just defaulting to null

Comment: Okay. I hope you know what is the problem here. PDO dont show error by default. It just sets the error code and error info. Thats why you didn't see any error.

Comment: Ok i added back my print result part with the changes you said before. Its showing Please Enter a Valid ID Tag - (id)

Comment: select * from player where player_id = '4f5520beefc1d'; My query is good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8550/discussion-between-john-ayers-and-shiplu)